# Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition don't power up

Tags: boot, dell-xps

I'm having a big trouble with my laptop. I'm from Spain and I'm currently travelling arround Thailand and I decided to carry my Laptop in this travel. The trouble is that when close the lip of my laptop, when open again the system don't power up. It becomes freeze and no way to power up or shuting down. To power up again I need to disconnect the battery, but in Thailand I don't have my TORX T5 screwdriver for remove the bottom case.

Anyone knows about this issue? I have A09 BIOS update already installed, so maybe it's not a BIOS problem. Maybe motherboard error?

My Laptop is a Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition L322X.

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Within the energy Settings (at least under Windows; not sure about your Ubuntu), you can define the behaviour of the notebook when the lid is closed. By default, it will enter sleep mode (aka energy save mode).

It appears, that sleep mode is not working properly on your system. Therefore, you might want to change the energy settings to do nothing when the lid is closed. However, make sure that the system does not stay powered on and runs into battery exhaustion.

There is a [related post](http://www.jx0.org/2013/12/dell-xps-13-developer-edition-review.html) which refers to a script for "lid checking" against unwanted awake from save mode with closed lid.

The freeze-on-suspend problem is discussed [here](http://xps13-9333.appspot.com/#suspend). It looks like a [kernel or driver issue](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=86241).

Comment: Hi Axel,

Yesterday night I updated my BIOS to version A11 and seems to work OK in Windows (but I don't tested it too much), in Linux, as you suggested, I blacklisted my *mei* and *mei_me* driver and seems to work, but now my system doesn't suspend on lip close. I have ElementaryOS on my laptop and can't configure the action for the lip close, but before the change, the system suspends automatically. Can I recover this? I need to patch my Kernel as suggested in Bugzilla?

Comment: Seems like magic, but now the laptop suspend and resume as expected. If new issues happen, I will tell you.

Comment: Fatally, the problem still happens. Are you sure that this problem is related as a Kernel issue? It's possible that this problem comes from the motherboard?

Comment: From a quick Google tour, I've got the impression, that it is probably a software issue. Obviously, only people suffering problems invest the time to write about their PC. It could be a hardware instability, but I would first update drivers and kernel before calling Dell. The Dell support forums might have further information.

Comment: Yesterday night, my laptop stopes while I was working normaly, then, the laptop didn't boot. Today, I removed the battery again and the sistem dtarted, but this time, the laptop freezed at Dell logo for a 8 secpnds and then start normaly. Now I'm passing a memscan on the laptop. Seems that is hardware issue, no?

Comment: More info: The system now doesn't reboot. When I click at reboot, the system shutdowns as spectet but don't wake up again, it's freezed and I need to remove the battery connector and put again. Now, with the battery, don't wake up, I left the connector unplugged. The only way of wake up the laptop is by connecting it to the power directly, and the battery connector unplugged. Finally, it seems a hardware error.

Comment: It is hard to tell. Could it be a cooling problem? Is the fan running? Have you had a look at the Dell support site? There are active forums and FAQ lists.

Comment: Finally seems to be a motherboard problem, because after 12 hours without trying to start the system, I tried to start it and no luck. Later, after some tries, the system started normally. So it's not a cooling problem, the fan is working as spected. Sometimes, the OS can't boot because the HD is not recognized, but after restart, the system start normally. I don't understand anything and I'm going crazy...